# Get taxonomy terms for posts that also have term from different taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 taxonomies: `book_category` and `book_publisher`.

On the `book_publisher` term archive page, I would like to display a list of terms from `book_category` taxonomy that also have posts from the queried `book_publisher` term (so that I won't have any empty ones).

The idea is that the user then clicks the `book_category` and gets a list of books from current `book_publisher` with selected `book_category` - that part is relatively easy to do.

Is there any way to do this without just manually getting all the posts from current `book_publisher` and then getting all their terms, as I ca imagine that being a bit too heavy with many posts in the database.

Comment: This question is answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/327150/13090